# Delphi TDateTimePicker Change Calendar Font

Tags: delphi

I need to change the font of the `TDateTimePicker` control to make it larger. The `Font` property only applies to the edit bar, and I made that one 12px, but need to do the same for the calendar. There's a Calendar control that backs this TDateTimePicker control, how do I get access to it?

I tried looking at other properties and searching for `.Calendar` or something that would expose the underlying Calendar but haven't had success.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`TDateTimePicker`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker) is a thin wrapper around a Win32 [DTP control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-control-reference).  The VCL does not expose access to the drop-down calendar.

However, you can send the `TDateTimePicker` a [`DTM_GETMONTHCAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getmonthcal) message (or use the [`DateTime_GetMonthCal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-datetime_getmonthcal) function):

> Gets the handle to a date and time picker's (DTP) child month calendar control.

Do note the following in the documentation:

> DTP controls create a child month calendar control when the user clicks the drop-down arrow (`DTN_DROPDOWN` notification). When the month calendar is no longer needed, it is destroyed (a `DTN_CLOSEUP` notification is sent on destruction). So your application must not rely on a static handle to the DTP control's child month calendar.

As such, you will have to manipulate the calendar in the [`TDateTimePicker.OnDropDown`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.OnDropDown) event, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
var
  CalendarWnd: HWND;
begin
  CalendarWnd := DateTime_GetMonthCal(DateTimePicker1.Handle);
  // use CalendarWnd as needed...
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: as @AmigoJack pointed out in comment, you can instead send the `TDateTimePicker` a [`DTM_SETMCFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-setmcfont) message (or use the [`DateTime_SetMonthCalFont()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-datetime_setmonthcalfont) function):

> Sets the font to be used by the date and time picker (DTP) control's child month calendar control.

```
DateTime_SetMonthCalFont(DateTimePicker1.Handle, DateTimePicker1.Font.Handle, DateTimePicker1.DroppedDown);
```

Comment: @AmigoJack thanks, I wasn't aware of that message. I have updated my answer

Comment: Somehow that `DateTime_SetMonthCalFont` line didn't work for me when placed in `FormShow` (`onShow`). Also, getting this error on `ord`: `Incompatible types: LongBool and Integer`. But I also tried `True/False` and the calendar font isn't getting updated.

Comment: @geneb. my bad, the `Ord()` was a copy/paste mistake from an earlier `Perform()`/`SendMessage()` example. `DateTime_SetMonthCalFont()` takes a `BOOL` instead, which a `Boolean` can be assigned to. Do you have the same problem if you move `DateTime_SetMonthCalFont()` to the `TDateTimePicker.OnDroppedDown` event?

Comment: Thanks, yes, same problem when using this line in `TDateTimePicker.OnDroppedDown`, the font is still unchanged. I made the 3rd param `True` just in case.

Comment: @geneb. what OS are you running this code on, and do you have Visual Styles enabled in your app manifest?

Comment: Windows 10 Home. I actually don't have a Manifest, I simply started up Delphi and did a File->New->Windows VCL Application, and added the `TDateTimePicker` to the form. In the `uses` clause I added `commctrl` to permit the `DateTime_SetMonthCalFont()` call. Then added the event function `TForm1.DateTimePicker1DropDown` with this SetMonthCalFont call. The event function does get called, which I verified with a MessageBox, but the SetMonthCalFont call simply doesn't change the font.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually needed, but make sure "Enable Runtime Themes" is checked in the [Manifest settings](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_Manifest) of your Project Options

Comment: Yes, "Enable Runtime Themes" is enabled there. I'll look some more